# verb like suffice for human subject

Tags: single-word-requests

We can say for example:

> It **suffices** to say that...

But I wonder if a similar verb exists that can be used for people(humans), e.g:

> He only **(...)** to explain the first part and skips over the second part, however, I find the second part more difficult. (I want to say: He(the author) has decided to avoid explaining the second part, because he has thought that it's been so uncomplicated_which is not the case about me of course_)

I know that I could say this

> He only explains the first part and...

and also this one

> He neglects to explain the second part and only explains the first part, however,...

but I feel I've heard another way for saying it too. I'm just trying to figure out if such word exists at all to fill the gap above.

I also found a very close option, which is the phrasal verb "settle for", but it doesn't apply to the example above, because the author has neglected explaining it more because of its "simplicity", whereas "settle for" is used in cases that the person "has not been able" to reach that amount of quality.(E.g: The team settled for a bronze medal.)

Thoughts?

Comment: TBH, your question is a bit unclear to me: 'It suffices to say...' means 'It is sufficient to say...' So why does saying 'he thought it sufficient to say...' or 'he thought explaining X would suffice', not meet the case?

Comment: I'd be tempted by one of these: "He only **bothers** to explain ...", "He is only **concerned** to explain ,,,", "He only **worries about** explaining ,,,", or perhaps if it's less deliberate "He only **manages** to explain ..." or "He only **succeeds** in explaining ...". In all these cases, you actually have a choice about where to put the "only", in some cases there are three options: "He **succeeds** in explaining _only_ ..." or "He **worries _only_ about** explaining ..."

Comment: @SteveLovell Those all communicate something other than the explanation sufficing. They imply that the author is lazy, or has a narrower focus, lacks competence... if M-J really wants something equivalent to 'suffice' surely we need something which related to further explanation not being necessary?

Comment: @Spagirl, M-J certainly _might_ want that. I wasn't sure, which is one reason this was offered only as a comment. My versions are certainly very close in meaning to the 3rd and 4th block quotes in the OP.

Comment: @SteveLovell Yeah, I'm still not entirely convinced of the OPs interpretation of 'suffice', but fair point, on that fourth blockquote particularly.

Comment: @SteveLovell I think "He only bothers to explain..." is most probably what I was looking for. But one final question is that, doesn't this have a disrespectful connotation? Am I complaining about the author if I use this? Assuming that the author "is not lazy" and is indeed a very respected person?

Comment: Yes, **bothers** does tend to imply laziness. You might like **deigns** as per the comments on @MaxWilliams answer. It has the implication that the person thinks it's beneath his dignity to explain the other item. It can come across as implying he's a bit 'big headed'. To avoid both extremes, I'd use "He was concerned to explain only ...".

Comment: @SteveLovell That's a great explanation. I wanted this exactly. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

"deigned" or "deigns"?

http://www.thefreedictionary.com/deign

> v. intr. To do something that one considers beneath one's dignity; condescend: wouldn't deign to greet the servant who opened the door. See Synonyms at stoop1.
>
> v.tr. To condescend to give or grant; vouchsafe: "Nor would we deign him burial of his men" (Shakespeare).

You could say "*He only deigned to explain the first part...*".  This is like saying "He only decided to explain the first part", and carries a connotation of **disapproval**, as if you're implying that he was being **lazy** to only explain the first part and not the others.

It's usually used sarcastically, as a way of saying "He thinks that it's beneath him to write explanations for everything."  In other words, that he is a bit arrogant.

NOTE:  I originally wrote "deemed", which isn't right.  Thanks to @Spagirl and @SteveLovell for pointing out my confusion.

Comment: This seems an odd usage of 'deem'. You 'deem a thing to be something', you don't just 'deem'. 'Deemed the results [to be] unsatisfactory', she deemed [the improvements] to be something he would value. So perhaps 'He only deemed the first part to require explanation' or 'he only deemed it necessary to explain the first part'. As your answer stands it seems as though you have confused it with 'deigned'.

Comment: @Spagirl. I agree about possible confusion with **deigned** here.

Comment: @Spagirl you might be right about the confusion.

Comment: @MaxWilliams Cheers. Are you leaving the answer as it stands?

Comment: sigh...I suppose not....will edit.

Answer (score 0):

Two possibilities come to mind:

"He omits an explanation for the first part."

> To leave out or exclude (someone or something), either intentionally or forgetfully.
>   "a significant detail was omitted from your story"

"He takes for granted that the first part requires no explanation."

> To assume that something is true without questioning it.
>   "those companies challenged beliefs that everyone else took for granted"